# Prevent BottomBar from rebuilding the entire application in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-change-notifier

I have an app with a bottom bar that is used to navigate between the three main tabs of the app using `AutoTabsRouter.pageView()`. The bottom bar is only visible in some parts of the app, so I need a function that controls its animation. Also depending on the bottom bar being visible or not, the `physics` of the `AutoTabsRouter.pageView()` changes between swipable and not. Since each page of the app is pretty complicated, I defined the following listenable:

```
class BottomBarModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  BottomBarModel(this.animationController);

  AnimationController animationController;
  bool isVisible = true;

  void toggleBar({required bool visibility}) {
    if (isVisible == visibility) {
      return;
    }
    if (visibility) {
      animationController.reverse();
    } else {
      animationController.forward();
    }
    isVisible = visibility
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

This way, I initialize the `BottomBar` using `ChangeNotifierProvider`, which sits just above the pageView, and access it anywhere in the app. It looks something like:

```
ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => BottomBarModel(animationController),
      child: AutoTabsRouter.pageView(
        physics: ???
            ? const ClampingScrollPhysics()
            : const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        routes: const [Section1(), Section2(), Section3()],
        builder: (context, very_expnesive_widget, _) {
          return Scaffold(
            bottomNavigationBar: BottomBar(),
            body: very_expnesive_widget,
          );
        },
      ),
    );
```

The problem is how do I change the physics of the pageView without rebuilding its very expensive children?

Comment: I answered this for you on slack.  You had your tab bar index in your widget, instead of your widget state.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz Sorry what do you mean? What Slack are you talking about?

Comment: Ahh, two people having exact same problem within 4 hours.  Odd, but perhaps happened. :)